# Dash to panel/ Dash to dock in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, 19.10

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 (fresh installation). In 19.04, I installed an application from Ubuntu Software called dash to panel or dash to dock (it was one of these 2- which one? I don't remember).

It removed the top bar and merged the clock and battery etc. in my dock as:

[image]

After switching to 19.10, I tried installing this, because I prefer to have larger "work" area. I searched for both of these in Ubuntu Software, but apparently, I didn't get any search results for these. I'm not sure have it works in Ubuntu- are these extensions not up for 19.10 yet? If yes, are there any alternatives for it? If no, what am I doing wrong? I'm 99.99% sure that it is one of these 2!

Comment: Are you running a Gnome Shell? If so have you installed gnome-tweaks?

Comment: It's Dash to Panel, install it from here: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/

Comment: @Logix I see this message when I go to this link: `"We cannot detect a running copy of GNOME on this system, so some parts of the interface may be disabled. See our troubleshooting entry for more information."`

Comment: @PaulBenson yes I am runnung Gnome: `GNOME Shell 3.34.1`. Yes I have installed gnome-tweaks, but it's extension option doesn't show me the required stuff (attached screenshot for the same)

Comment: @Logix that linked helped. I don't know why it shows that message, but I was certainly able to get it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just upgraded to 19.10 myself from 19.04.  Dash to Dock seems to have stopped working.  I just installed Dash to panel and that seems to work.  You can position it on either the top or bottom.  And I do like the extra space it provides.

For me I installed it as a gnome extension from the website.  https://extensions.gnome.org/

You will need to make sure to have the Gnome Integration Add-on installed in Firefox if it isn't installed already.  If it is installed you will see a black foot print towards the top right of the Firefox browser for the Gnome Integration add-on and that can take you to the website.

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: I installed this from Ubuntu Software. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: It does not work. In ubuntu software center, it's enabled, but nothing happened. Already the top bar is here...

Comment: I also have upgraded from 19.04 and `Dash to Panel` stopped working. I solved it by removing and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but on the Ubuntu login screen, I clicked on the small gear icon to the left of "Sign In" and instead of "Ubuntu" selected "Gnome". Now Dock to Dash is working again!